# New line characters not working in pymsteams text

Tags: python, linux, text, microsoft-teams, newline

I got the following output from a Linux machine and I am trying to push it to the MS Teams channel. However, the output format changes when text is displayed in the team channel. The new line character does not work.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("ip addr | grep bond0")
pwd_out=stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
new_text="Link Status:"+"\n" +  pwd_out
print(new_text)
myTeamsMessage.text(new_text)
```

Python terminal output:

```
`> Link Status:
6: ens1f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
9: ens2f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
10: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
11: bond0.400@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.40.10/24 brd 192.168.40.255 scope global noprefixroute bond0.400
12: bond0.501@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.51.16/24 brd 192.168.51.255 scope global noprefixroute bond0.501`
```

MSTEAMS output:

```
payload: {'text': 'Link Status:\n6: ens1f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000\n9: ens2f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000\n10: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000\n11: bond0.400@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000\n    inet 192.168.40.10/24 brd 192.168.40.255 scope global noprefixroute bond0.400\n12: bond0.501@bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000\n    inet 192.168.51.16/24 brd 192.168.51.255 scope global noprefixroute bond0.501\n'}
```

Is there a way to get the MS team's output the same as the Python terminal output?

Comment: have you tried `new_text="Link Status:"+"\r\n" +  pwd_out`

Comment: Please try using \r\n as mentioned by JonSG above.

Comment: "Link Status:"+"\r\n" +  pwd_out does not work

Comment: Use any of the below it gives same output - new_text="Link Status:"+"\n\r" +  "test123",  new_text="Link Status:"+"\r\r" +  "test123",  new_text="Link Status:"+"\n\n" +  "test123" - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx8s5.png

Comment: Using "\n\n" works as intended, having tested it alongside other options:

new_text="Link Status:"+"\n\r" - Does not work
new_text="Link Status:"+"\r\r" - Does not work
new_text="Link Status:"+"\n\n" - Works